# I need to capture some values ​outside the while loop

Tags: php

I need help with something, I have this code

```
$queryF = "SELECT descripcion FROM bot_pedidos WHERE id_origen = '1587871428' AND id_pedido_enc = 51";
$executeF = mysqli_query($conn, $queryF);

while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($executeF)){
    $h = $fila["descripcion"];

    $msj = $h."<br>";
    
 
}   
echo $msj;
```

And it brought me only this

```
M-CE285A
```

But I need that show this

```
M-35A/36A/85A/78A
M-CE285A
```

Only take the last one, I know that it is because the "echo" is outside the loop but there is any way that I can show all outside the loop?

Comment: Hint: `$msj .= $h."<br>";` or replace `$msj = $h."<br>"` with `echo $h."<br>"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change this line like this (add the dot)

```
$msj .= $h."<br>";
```